# How to make a Regular expression in C# for parsing python string Literals?

Tags: c#, regex

I've been trying to parse python language string via Regex of C#

python strings are as follow :

- "string1"
- "string2\" it is still string till now"
- """This is a \r
  \na multiline\r 
  \npython string"""
- """ this is also a multiline string\""" but it doesnt end here, 
  \n it ends with all three quotes together without escape sequence so it ends here ->"""

I have to look for a condition where my string matches this..

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(input, "^\"" + @"[\w\s\W]*" + "[^\\]"+"\\" +"$") || Regex.IsMatch(input, "^\"\"\"" + @"[\w\s\W]*" + "\"\"\"$"))
{ // do something then }
```

Comment: This does not have an escaped double quote in it `"string2/" it is still string till now"` does it ?

Comment: I don't think escaped anything is honored in raw literals are they ? Also from what I remember, in Python `\"""` cannot be defined to mean the end of the raw literal. Ok, so it won't be seen as the end.

Comment: `"string\"is continued"` i want this to parse, but not 
`"this to parse\"`

Comment: I think @sln meant that you used `/"` when you should have used `\"` in string2.

Comment: yeah right, sorry i edited my question

Comment: Double quote is easy, say mid stream  `(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*"(?s:[^"\\]|\\.)*"`

Comment: The problem is Python has obscure rules on raw literals.

Comment: What would be the output for `"this to parse\"\n"""foo bar"""`

Comment: @Avinash
`"this to parse\"\n"`
`""`
`foo bar` identifiers 
`""` string
`"` an string that didnt end so its invalid

Comment: Why it isn't `"this to parse\"\n` a separate  and `"""foo bar"""` another separate string?

Comment: oops i guess i intrepreted your question wrong, 
I didnt notice you were trying to give new line with `\n`..
I need my regex to work with C# and not with python...
Your answer is valid for python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
(?:u|r|ur|ru)?(?:(?P<q1>'''|""")(?:[^'"\\]*(?:\\.|(?!\1)['"]))*[^'"\\]*(?P=q1)|(?P<q2>'|")(?:[^'"\\\n]*(?:\\.|(?!\1)['"]))*[^'"\\\n]*(?P=q2))
```

[Demo.](http://regex101.com/r/uM1pH1/1)

Explanation:

```
(?: // first, any combination of "r" and "u" (optionally)
    u|r|ur|ru
)?
(?: // next, either a multi- or single line string
    (?P<q1> // create a named capturing group for the quotes
        '''|"""
    )
    (?:
        [^'"\\]* // then match anything except quotes and backslashes
        (?: // if there's a quote or backslash, check if the string ends here
            \\. // if there's a backslash next, match the next two characters unconditionally
            |
            (?!\1)['"] // otherwise, if there is NOT a closing quote, match any quote
        )
    )* // do this as many times as possible, then...
    [^'"\\]* //...match anything that's no quote or backslash one last time...
    (?P=q1) //...and end with the quote the string started with.
    |
    // down below the same thing for single line strings.
    (?P<q2>
        '|"
    )
    (?:
        [^'"\\\n]*
        (?:
            \\.
            |
            (?!\1)['"]
        )
    )*
    [^'"\\\n]*
    (?P=q2)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The below regex would match all the python string literals which are enclosed within `"` or `"""`.

```
"""(?:(?!(?<![\\\/])""").)*"""|"(?:(?!(?<![\\\/])").)*"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hJ7nT4/3)

Note that i have included `s` DOTALL modifier in the above regex. It won't work for incomplete quotes.

Comment: how will i make it work in C#? If you can answer that as well

Comment: `It won't work for incomplete quotes.`, is this ok for you? I don't know how there must be incomplete quotes in the input string...

Comment: im constructing a compiler for my course, for that i need to parse python strings... so it includes quotes.. sir

Answer (score 0):

```
^(".*")$
```

You can use this as well.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hJ7nT4/2

Comment: The regex is of PHP, i dont know why but its not working this way,
i dont want `"this to get parsed\"`